# "Community Eval stats" link in the moderator tools is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

It appears we have a new "Informative Page" in the moderator tools, "Community Eval stats". But it doesn't seem to be working, on Programmers the link leads to the all familiar "Oops! Something Bad Happened" page.

[image]

The actual error seems to be:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This might just be because it's fairly new (apparently it doesn't even exist on SF or SU yet), but I thought of reporting it just in case it was supposed to be working or even not be there at all.

Comment: Repro on chem .

Comment: broken on webapps too. [su] doesn't have it though.

Comment: I get [the same result on Skeptics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr3il.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right you are - a new feature we're working on leaked out, I'll just throw "due to the hurricane" on there because that's all I've heard about for the past few days.  The next build will disable the link.

Answer (score 4):

If it's the link I think it is (I'm on my phone right now, so checking is a bit painful), it's not supposed to exist yet or possibly at all. :)

Comment: Nothing exploded then? Disappointing... :P

Comment: @YannisRizos it exploded so hard it *existed*

Comment: I blame the hurricane.